# Substr python version

Tags: javascript, python

Lets say I have a string,

```
'88672931'
```

Now in JavaScript doing

```
string.substr(4,4)
```

returns "2931" Which way is more pythonic of doing this? I have 3 ways of doing it so far I'm just curious to which way is more pythonic for future reference

```
'88672931'[4:][:4]
'88672931'[-4:]
'88672931'[4:4+4]
```

Or is there an even more pythonic way of doing this? I'm asking this because I want to start doing things more pythonic and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'88672931'[4:8]` would be the direct equivalent of the JavaScript example you gave.

If you're specifically wanting the last 4 characters, `'88672931'[-4:]` would most be Pythonic.